# Is necessary to buy an exclusive domain just to develop apps in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-addin

Based on this article from Technet https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161236.aspx, it's written that I need to buy a new domain to setup my SharePoint Server to support apps. Is necessary to buy a domain even in a development environment? You know, I'm just learning to build apps for SP2013 with a single VM configuration, not pretending to build production solutions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it won't impact the outcome for production even if you have a separate domain for SharePoint Addins in production. It is used as a security measure, but that requirement may not exist in a development environment.